# Remove an image from html5 canvas that has been placed there using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have the following function that has drawn an image onto the HTML5 canvas using JavaScript:

```
function drawStartButton(){
            image.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(image, 260.5, 60);
            };
            image.src = "StartButton.png";

            var boundingBox = myGameCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();

            boundingBox.onmousemove = function(e){
                var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                var pixels = context.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1);
            }
        }
```

The image is going to be used as a button, which will call another function when clicked. The function that I want to call when the button is clicked is:

```
function drawLevelOneElements(){
            image.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(image, 50, 30, 20, 20); 


            };
            image.src = "1.png";
}
```

I've added an event listener to the canvas, which listens for a click on the button, and calls that function when the click occurs. This currently works correctly, however, although the function `drawLevelOneElements()` is called, and drawn to the canvas, the image drawn by the call to `drawStartButton()` is also still displayed on the canvas, so I have the contents of both functions displayed on the canvas at the same time.

What I want to happen, is when the button is clicked, the button then disappears, and the elements drawn by `drawLevelOneElements` are what is displayed on the canvas, without the start button being there any more.

Could someone tell me how I can clear the image drawn by `drawStartButton()` from the canvas after it has been drawn on the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you can clear the entire canvas by setting its width or height values.

If you want to clear one area of the canvas, you could do that by drawing a fillRect on that area - set the fillStyle to be the same colour as the background colour of the canvas, for example.

```
 context.fillStyle = this.fill;
 context.fillRect( x, y, width, height );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the end, I found a function called context.clearRect(x, y, width, height); and that seems to have worked